# How to create a column in pandas dataframe with percentages, and more

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two types of dataframes:

Dataframe `AID`:

```
AID FID ANumOfF
1   X   1
1   Y   5
2   Z   6
2   A   1
2   X   11
2   B   18
```

Dataframe `VID`:

```
VID FID VNumOfF
1A  X   10
1A  A   500
2A  A   62
2A  B   10
2A  C   30
2A  X   23
```

1- I want to create a new column in each Dataframe that would calculate the % each FID holds for each VID. So the results for the above for example would be the following:

NEW Dataframe `AID`:

```
AID FID ANumOfF  PercentF
1   X   1        0.167  (1/6)
1   Y   5        0.833  (5/6)
2   Z   6        0.167  (6/36)
2   A   1        0.028
2   X   11       0.305
2   B   18       0.5
```

NEW Dataframe `VID`:

```
VID FID VNumOfF  PercentF
1A  X   10       0.02
1A  A   500      0.98
2A  A   62       0.50
2A  B   10       0.08
2A  C   30       0.24
2A  X   23       0.18
```

As of now I know that the following code gives me the sums for each AID/VID:

```
AID.groupby('AID')['ANumFS'].sum()
VID.groupby('VID')['VNumFS'].sum()
```

2- After that I want to create a new dataframe that looks at the "overlap" of each pair of VID and AID that exists. And it would sum up the product of the percentages that they would both share. So for the new dataframes produced above, we would get the following:

Since `AID=1` and `VID=1A` only have `FID=X` in common, Overlap calculation would be: `0.167*0.02 = 0.00334`

`AID=2` and `VID=2A` have `FIDs A, B and X` in common, so overlap calculation would be: `0.028*0.5 + 0.305*0.18 + 0.5*0.08 = 0.1089`

```
AID   VID   Overlap
1     1A    0.00334
1     2A    0.03006
2     1A    0.03354
2     2A    0.1089
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what's your code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) and [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for creating new columns:

```
AID['PercentF'] = AID['ANumOfF'].div(AID.groupby('AID')['ANumOfF'].transform('sum'))
print (AID)
   AID FID  ANumOfF  PercentF
0    1   X        1  0.166667
1    1   Y        5  0.833333
2    2   Z        6  0.166667
3    2   A        1  0.027778
4    2   X       11  0.305556
5    2   B       18  0.500000

VID['PercentF'] = VID['ANumOfF'].div(VID.groupby('VID')['ANumOfF'].transform('sum'))
print (VID)
  VID FID  ANumOfF  PercentF
0  1A   X       10  0.019608
1  1A   A      500  0.980392
2  2A   A       62  0.496000
3  2A   B       10  0.080000
4  2A   C       30  0.240000
5  2A   X       23  0.184000
```

Then `inner` join by [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), multiple columns and last `groupby` with aggregating `sum`:

```
df = pd.merge(AID, VID, on='FID')
df['Overlap'] = df.PercentF_x.mul(df.PercentF_y)
df = df.groupby(['AID','VID'], as_index=False)['Overlap'].sum()
print (df)
   AID VID   Overlap
0    1  1A  0.003268
1    1  2A  0.030667
2    2  1A  0.033224
3    2  2A  0.110000
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok first use [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to get a table like this:

```
AID Sum(ANumOfF)
1   6
2   36
```

Then [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) that DataFrame with the original one:

```
AID FID ANumOfF TotalNum
1   X   1       6
1   Y   5       6
2   Z   6       36
2   A   1       36
2   X   11      36
2   B   18      36
```

And then finally get the percentage by dividing the `ANumOfF` column by the `TotalNum` column.

Hope this helps.